# How do I customize go-present template?

Tags: go, go-present

I am new to Go and just stumbled upon Go's `present` package which I imported via `go get golang.org/x/tools/present`.

Is there any way to customize the look of the presentation? E.g. via adjusting the default css file?

If so where are the files used for the style? I cannot find the package anywhere in my Go path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the only way to change presentation styles is to modify library files directly.

If you use `vgo`:

```
$GOPATH/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@<version>/cmd/present
```

Otherwise:

```
$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/present
```

Of cause first you need to download `present` package: `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/present`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am a bit lost. Is there a css file that I could modify. Or what do you mean with "modify library files directly".

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume you have a directory `myslides` with some .slide files in it.

1. Create a subfolder `theme` in `myslides`.
2. Copy the folders `template` and `static` from  $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/present to that new `theme` directory
3. Start `present` with a new parameter -base: `present -base theme`

Modify the styles and template files. Most small things are in `styles.css`.

If you change the template files, then you need to stop and restart `present`. If your are changing the styles only, then a reload in the browser will do (take care to disable the cache.)

Comment: Clearly, the author of the selected answer did not know about the `-base` flag. This should be the selected answer.